# type "viewController" does not conform protocol "PathMenuDelegate"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

- I just start learning swift.
- I installed Cocoapod and tried to see if i can implemented.
- i truly dont know how to fix this problem, the rest of the code will be provided down below.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()



  let menuItemImage = UIImage(named: "bg-menuitem")!
  let menuItemHighlitedImage = UIImage(named: "bg-menuitem-highlighted")!

  let starImage = UIImage(named: "icon-star")!

  let starMenuItem1 = PathMenuItem(image: menuItemImage, highlightedImage: menuItemHighlitedImage, contentImage: starImage)

  let starMenuItem2 = PathMenuItem(image: menuItemImage, highlightedImage: menuItemHighlitedImage, contentImage: starImage)

  let starMenuItem3 = PathMenuItem(image: menuItemImage, highlightedImage: menuItemHighlitedImage, contentImage: starImage)

  let starMenuItem4 = PathMenuItem(image: menuItemImage, highlightedImage: menuItemHighlitedImage, contentImage: starImage)

  let starMenuItem5 = PathMenuItem(image: menuItemImage, highlightedImage: menuItemHighlitedImage, contentImage: starImage)

  let items = [starMenuItem1, starMenuItem2, starMenuItem3, starMenuItem4, starMenuItem5]

  let startItem = PathMenuItem(image: UIImage(named: "bg-addbutton")!,
      highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "bg-addbutton-highlighted"),
      contentImage: UIImage(named: "icon-plus"),
      highlightedContentImage: UIImage(named: "icon-plus-highlighted"))

  let menu = PathMenu(frame: view.bounds, startItem: startItem, items: items)

  menu.delegate = self

  menu.startPoint = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height - 30.0)
  menu.menuWholeAngle = CGFloat(M_PI) - CGFloat(M_PI/5)
  menu.rotateAngle = -CGFloat(M_PI_2) + CGFloat(M_PI/5) * 1/2
  menu.timeOffset = 0.0
  menu.farRadius = 110.0
  menu.nearRadius = 90.0
  menu.endRadius = 100.0
  menu.animationDuration = 0.5

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


  }
  ```
- Delegate protocol (PathMenuDelegate)
  _ how to implement the rest of code show below into the viewDidLoad

  ```
   func pathMenu(menu: PathMenu, didSelectIndex idx: Int)
   func pathMenuDidFinishAnimationClose(menu: PathMenu)
   func pathMenuDidFinishAnimationOpen(menu: PathMenu)
   func pathMenuWillAnimateOpen(menu: PathMenu)
   func pathMenuWillAnimateClose(menu: PathMenu)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
　　　　
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       ~~~
        menu.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(menu)
    }
}
extension ViewController: PathMenuDelegate {
    func didSelect(on menu: PathMenu, index: Int) {
        print("Select the index : \(index)")
    }
    func willStartAnimationOpen(on menu: PathMenu) {
        print("Menu will open!")
    }

    func willStartAnimationClose(on menu: PathMenu) {
        print("Menu will close!")
    }

    func didFinishAnimationOpen(on menu: PathMenu) {
        print("Menu was open!")
    }

    func didFinishAnimationClose(on menu: PathMenu) {
        print("Menu was closed!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put these code in viewDidLoad.

Make the respective viewController conform to the `PathMenuDelegate`

And Start typing the protocol functions you'll get suggestions for 'em

Answer (score 0):

Everything you're questioning, just see the author's sample code here: Very simple and straight forward. Those delegate's functions are just for handling events from the lib. And the sample here just prints something to show you that, "Your code works".

https://github.com/pixyzehn/PathMenu/blob/master/PathMenu-Sample/PathMenu-Sample/ViewController.swift